# JSON.NET Converter: If a given value is missing use default deserialization

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a COM interface known both to Delphi and .NET.
Both .NET and Delphi classes implement this interface.

I am using a Converter during deserialization and am able to detect whether or not the class to be instantiated is a .net or delphi class.

Everything is working fine for a Delphi class.
However if a .NET class needs to be instatiated I need to be able to create and populate the .NET object.

Refer to code snippet below.

```
  class DelphiTypesJsonConverter : Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter
  {
    private const string XMLKEY = "__XML";

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
      var jObject = JObject.Load(reader);
      var xmlBlob = jObject.GetValue(XMLKEY);
      if (xmlBlob != null)
      {
        var delphiObject = CreateDelphiCOMObject(xmlBlob);// Object will be created in Delphi. This works!
        return delphiObject;
      }

      // The implementing class is a .NET class
      // Just proceed with the default behaviour based on the $type identifier.
      // How can I now create the type that would have been created if this converter would have not been executed.

      return ????;   
    }
  }
```

**EDIT**

In the meantime I found out that calling

```
return serializer.Deserialize(reader);
```

returns exactly what I need. But this works only if I have not called:

```
JObject.Load(reader);
```

before.
But I need to call JObject.Load(reader) to be able to determine if dealing with a Delphi or .NET object.
Getting closer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works. Have spent hours on this.

```
   public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
      var jToken = JToken.Load(reader);
      if (jToken.HasValues)
      {
        var xmlBlob = jToken[XMLKEY];
        if (jToken.First.Path == XMLKEY)
        { 
          var delphiObject = CoreFactory.CrossPlatformProperties.DeserializeDelphiObject(xmlBlob.Value<string>());
          return delphiObject;
        }
      }
      return serializer.Deserialize(jToken.CreateReader());
    }
```

Comment: What if you just use `var xmlBlob = jToken[XMLKEY]`?  Then you should be able to get rid of the need for loading the JObject from a new reader.

Comment: @Brian, thanks! You beat me to it, that did the trick!! I was just digging deeper into JToken...